# summing the numbers after appendText to a textField

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, appendtext

as3 using appendText.  I'm simply stringing out numbers like entering from a button press.

```
key2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, thisButkey2);
function thisButkey2 (e:MouseEvent):void{
    displayNums.appendText("2") ;

}
key3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, thisButkey3);
function thisButkey3 (e:MouseEvent):void{
    displayNums.appendText("3") ;

}
```

How do I total the string text into one number?  I'd like to find out if it is > 100.

I solved it -  It simply needed to be turned into a Number.

```
keyEnter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, thisButEnter);
function thisButEnter (e:MouseEvent):void{
    totalSum = Number(displayNums.text)
    if ( totalSum > 100){
    clearNums();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,processentry)
var entry:int;
var sum:int;

function processentry(e)
{
  trace ("hello "+e.keyCode)
  entry = e.keyCode - 48;
  sum += entry;
  trace(sum);
}
```

The first 'trace' simply makes clear what's happening when you press a key. We subtract 48 from the keyCode because the ASCII keyCode for '0' is '48' and the other digits' keyCodes go up sequentially. It should be easy for you to adapt this to your own case. Just let your textfield append the current 'entry'. You can put the 'sum' into another textfield or do something else with it.

Comment: i misspoke my question.  I'm creating a "calculator" like input.  click the button 4 , display "4".  Click the button 3, display "43" (using appendText) .  So I would like to turn that "43" into a number  - so I can compare it to 100.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I solved the problem.  It is a simple Number(displayNums.text)            keyEnter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, thisButEnter);
function thisButEnter (e:MouseEvent):void{
 totalSum = Number(displayNums.text)
 if ( totalSum > 100){
 clearNums();
 }
 
}